# POSTGRES Aggregated function in Group BY

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I have the below Postgres code where I would like to Group BY `"Personal CC"` but for obvious reasons I cannot do this for aggregated fields.

If I do not put the `Group BY` and then I am getting the `"Number of Assistant Supervisors in Same Month"` `Personal CC` which is wrong.

Please help me on how to include the sum. Yes, I did some research and got to know we could use INNER JOIN but I failed miserably.

1. The desired result should be the sum Personal CC in Descending Order
2. The Sum should only be for the Month and Year I have given below but
   it takes the whole Year Values which is wrong
3. I just need to include the Sum of Personal CC in Group by if not
   please give us a solution on how can I get the sum by not including
   it in Group BY
4. I have not read the documentation BUT I AM CONSTANTLY RESEARCHING ON
   IT

For Each Sponsor, I have various country Monthly cc. Personal CC values. For each month. I would like to sum them to get a unique summed up value

```
 SELECT 
        extended_downline."Sponsor FBO ID"
        ,extended_downline."Sponsor Name"
        ,mcc.processing_month__c AS "Processing Month"
        ,mcc.processing_year__c AS "Processing Year"

        ,sum(mcc.personal_cc_mtd__c) AS "Personal CC"
        ,sum("Same Month") as "Number of Assistant Supervisors in Same Month"
        ,bool_or(mcc.current_month_active__c) AS "Current Month Active"

    FROM extended_downline
    LEFT OUTER JOIN connect.monthly_cc__c mcc ON mcc.distributor__c = extended_downline.sponsor_distributor__c
        AND mcc.op_company__c = extended_downline."Operating Company"
        AND (
            (
                mcc.processing_year__c = '2017'
                AND mcc.processing_month__c = 10
                )
            )
    WHERE extended_downline."Same Month" <> 0
        AND extended_downline."Generation" <> 0
        AND mcc.personal_cc_mtd__c IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY
        extended_downline."Sponsor FBO ID"
        ,extended_downline."Sponsor Name"    
        ,mcc.processing_year__c
        ,mcc.processing_month__c
        ,mcc.personal_cc_mtd__c
        ,extended_downline."Same Month"

    ORDER BY "Personal CC" DESC LIMIT 20
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql?

Comment: MySQL / postgressql - do you really mean both RDBMs or did you add extra tags?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  Your request doesn't make sense.

Comment: Such a `GROUP BY` would make no sense. What would be the meaning? Maybe you misunderstand `GROUP BY`; did you read the documentation?

Comment: Thanks @LaurenzAlbe yes if not how can i include the Sum of Personal CC for only the Year and Month?

Comment: Yes, it is probably the best thing if you add sample data and the output you want. I cannot understand it from the query you provide.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Order By ColumnPosition`

For example:

```
Order By 4 desc
```